# Is there free will?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

From what I've understood about the answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118681/determinism-and-quantum-computing) quantum physics doesn't contradict determinism, but instead it simply isn't achievable only because of our universe's nature: we are unable to detect particles without affecting them.

So, is our universe deterministic, independently from the fact that we can or cannot predict it?

Does that mean that this was the only possible evolving of our universe? (implying that we have no free will)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about the "supernatural" which is, by definition, not within the realm of physics.

Comment: The answer you refer to does *not* represent a mainstream view.

Comment: @Danu I really dislike this idea of "mainstream". It implies a certain appeal to authority which has no place in science.

Comment: I used that word to indicate something that doesn't normally happen. It's not normal a body that can perceive particle through a different reality, but what if it simply does that?

Comment: Simply eliminating the word "supernatural" from the question doesn't fundamentally alter it. "a body that doesn't belong to this reality" would still be a supernatural body.

Comment: _What about a body that doesn't belong to this reality and can perceive every particle in this reality at any moment without affect them, could It predict the state of those particles at every other moments?_  As with Daniel above, I don't think mainstream is the correct word (for the same reason). But this part of your question, no offence intended, makes no sense to me  and any answers would seem to be entirely opinion based. You seem to be asking, in effect, does god, or something godlike, exist? I can't see how physics can answer that question.

Comment: @AcidJazz Not if God exist but: if it exist can It predict our universe?

Comment: Still I would argue, this is not anything physics can answer and it is more a philosophy based question. Regards

Comment: What I really wanted to ask was if the universe is deterministic independently from the fact that we can or cannot predict it, the supernatural body was just an exemple

Comment: Have you ever made a choice that you regretted?  What if you could go back to re-live that moment?  But there's a catch!  You have to un-learn everything that you learned since then.  When you have your re-do, everything will be _exactly_ as it was the first time.  You will know exactly what you knew then, no more.  You will feel exactly what you felt then.  If our world is haunted by angels and demons, they will whisper to you exactly what they whispered the first time.  Will you choose differently?  If yes, then what's your justification for thinking so?  If no, then where's your free will?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this is really a philosophy question so I am going to give a philosophy response. Despite it not being an actual physics question it is an interesting question nonetheless that many people have asked at one point or another and it is nice to give a coherent response to these sorts of things:

Whats actually kind of interesting is that even if the universe was completely and utterly classical and deterministic and if it was possible to know the positions and velocities of every particle within a radius $ R $ to perfect precision, you still would not be able to make predictions with 100% accuracy.

Lets say for example that you wanted to predict what the world was going to be like 1 year from now, so you gather information about all particles within one light year and throw them into your simulator and wait for it to churn out a response. The issue with this is that it doesn't take into account the back reaction of the simulator on the world around it and there is not any way to perfectly account for it.

If the informational content of a system containing the simulator is $X$, the information contained within the simulator must be $\leq X $ with the equality happening when the system consists of **only** the simulator. Now of course you could thermodynamically isolate the simulator from the system and account for it in your system as a simple heat generator, but that introduces approximations which will eventually cause divergences in the chaotic system you are modeling.

An even better way of seeing this is as follows (this one hinges on the speed of causality being the speed of light which is true for our universe): I want to simulate the world for a year so I take all of the information about the current state of earth, travel two light years away set up an exact replica of earth and the surroundings (one edge is 1 light years away, the other is 3 light years away) then let it evolve for a year, get my perfect answer, go back to earth and find... That all of my information is 5 (3 years to set up, 1 year to simulate, 2 years to get back) years out of date! I wasn't able to get any information that would let me predict your behavior perfectly in advance!

In a completely unrelated note, if you look into the issue with more detail you may find that the concept of free will as is normally espoused (non determinism) implies that you react randomly without stimulus, but that is an entirely different issue.

Comment: I couldn't agree more, in fact what I wanted to say was that no body can or will predict the future nor the past or be useful. What I asked is if determinism could be true, independently from what we can predict, so that our universe could be considered the only possible one.

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions. It encourages people to ask them, which we do not want.

Comment: Sorry, where should such questions be answered?

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means a settled issue, the answer you linked to makes some assumptions; with most things related to interpretation of quantum mechanics, if you ask ten physicists they'll argue in ten different ways and come up with perhaps 3 or 5 different conclusions. My personal view is that QM is not deterministic because I'll postulate that my conscious experience at any given moment is described by a well defined classical computational state (I assume that in principle you could simulate me on a sufficiently powerful classical computer, which implies my claim). The set of all possible computational states then defines a preferred basis, therefore the (effective) non-deterministic collapse of the wavefunction is essential. So, in deterministic no-collapse theories (MWI-like theories), the wavefunction does evolve deterministically, but in which sector of the multiverse I end up is not deterministic. In fact it's just a matter of all these states existing a priori with some probability amplitude, time evolution is just an illusion.

Comment: I don't like your talk of probability amplitudes partly because it is unlikely to be understood correctly by every likely reader of the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Quantum physics doesn't contradict determinism

Correct

> instead it simply isn't achievable only because of our human nature. We are unable to detect particles without affecting them.

That is not right. The physical world didn't change when people evolved and there is nothing special about humans.

You can't predict outcomes with certainty for two different reasons. Firstly you don't have enough information to do so and there is no way even in principle that you could. Secondly the universe evolves into parts each of which acts as if it is the only part.  Since the view each part has is equally valid we can't say one is wrong and the other is right. But we have to accept that the views are different for each part yet part of the view each has is their inability to be aware of the other.

There only indication that the other part exists is that the physicists on each part can use the same equations that predict the continuous separation into two parts that have their own views and can't influence each other.

> Does that mean that free will doesn't exist and so this is the only possible universe (presuming that the big bang would be the same), but we simply can't predict the past nor the future because of our nature?

The universe evolves into different parts. These parts will feel and act like different things happened. They will be like different worlds and since they are independent they will feel like they are a complete world to itself.

So the kind of determinism where you can predict your personal view later on is not the determinism that is going on. You can have determinism and still not be able to place bets where you always win. Not unless your bets are that the universe evolves into different parts and one part will describe one thing as happening and the other part will descdibe this other thing as happening and each part will eventually act in a manner consistent with it being the only part.

It is deterministic if you think of it as one connected object continuously changing in time like a drawing with time as the vertical axis and you draw a tree branching as it reaches to the sky. If the branches can't be aware of the other branches and you think of an isolated slice of now. The now skices tge three into these different pieces each of which can think of itself as alone (by ignoring the equations that describe its past). But from the point of view of a piece there was no way it could have know that it became that piece instead of a different branch.

> What about a body that doesn't belong to this reality and can perceive every particle in this reality at any moment without affect them, could It predict the state of those particles at every other moments?

That is fiction. And there isn't a thing to observe. The branches are themselves the reality. And them being different and independent is what it means for something to happen. The rest is just details and the math.

There isn't for instance some true configuration of the particles. There are numbers assigned to each configuration and sometimes those numbers are small or even zero.

The values of the numbers nearby and how they vary nearby influence how they change in time. And if you have two regions of configurations where the numbers are nonzero each will act like it is the only region where things are nonzero unless the regions move over time to have where one is nonzero moves to overlap another region where it is nonzero.

So there isn't a configuration there is a whole range of configurations that aren't "the" configuration but instead collectively can act like an independent thing.  The independent things are worlds for all intents and purposes. And that is the reality. That whole independent branch. And it isn't seen. It is. And yes it changes and the whole reason anything feels like anything happens is because it branches into parts that become independent.

That said. There is a theory called dBB (de Broglie Bohm) theory where there even more information. It is like it says there is one correct configuration and that its streamline is affected by the probability current and all the other branches just are somehow not as special because the special chosen configuration wasn't guided into them. In that case there is complete determinism of the usual type if only you knew which initial configuration was the special one.

But then you have to ask if the same configuration is chosen to be special when you "redo the universe" and you still have to assign numbers to all the other configurations, just one of them also gets to be special.

Every branch acts like it is the only branch in which case it acts the same as if the special configuration was one that ended up in it.